# Invalid syntax when trying to run python script

Tags: python, syntax-error

I have an issue when trying to run the following function I throws an error invalid syntax:

```
    def usage():
    print """
    -h --help       Usage
    -b --myId       My Id
    -p --myImg      My primary image
    -s --myImg2     My secondary image
    -i --myfile     My file
    -e --env        Set env
  """
```

error:

```
    """
  ^
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Could someone help me with this? thanks in advance!

Comment: Is it python3?.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is missing proper indentation and also the parenthesis for the `print()` command

```
def usage():
    print ("""
    -h --help       Usage
    -b --myId       My Id
    -p --myImg      My primary image
    -s --myImg2     My secondary image
    -i --myfile     My file
    -e --env        Set env
  """)

#output
usage()

    -h --help       Usage
    -b --myId       My Id
    -p --myImg      My primary image
    -s --myImg2     My secondary image
    -i --myfile     My file
    -e --env        Set env
```

Answer (score 0):

print, just like any other function should be called with parenthesis containing the arguments. Meaning, in your case it would be:

```
def usage():
    print("""
-h --help       Usage
-b --myId       My Id
-p --myImg      My primary image
-s --myImg2     My secondary image
-i --myfile     My file
-e --env        Set env
  """)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code isn't indented properly and for multiline string use parenthesis () for the `print` statement ( In python 3x parenthesis is required ).

```
def usage():
    print("""
          -h --help       Usage
          -b --myId       My Id
          -p --myImg      My primary image
          -s --myImg2     My secondary image
          -i --myfile     My file
          -e --env        Set env
          """)


usage()
```